# How to convert an MVC4 application using "InProc" sessionState to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5, session-state

I have an application in MVC4 using that was hosted on a single server until now. The session was handled like this :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
```

Now, I would like to port this application to Azure and of course, to support multiple instances. I read many blogs, I could find solutions using AppFabric, AzureStorage, SQL Azure where you have to delete sessions manually... etc.

Is there a solution to make the app use SQL Azure to store its session and without having to clean session manually ? It seems strange to me that sessions seem to be such a big topic on Azure.

I saw there is a possibility to use Universal "Default Profile Providers"
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx

From what I understand, we just need to do an
Install-Package system.web.Providers

and then add :

```
  <sessionstate mode="Custom" customprovider="DefaultSessionProvider">
        <providers>
                      <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider"  connectionstringname="DefaultConnection" applicationname="/">
         </add></providers>
    </sessionstate>
```

Is this still the way to go in Visual Studio 2012 + MVC4 + .Net 4.5 ?

Thank you very much in advance for your replies.

Comment: I'm considering the same issue, how did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

We use the Universal provider in our app. It is MVC4 and hosted on Azure. It still seems like the best way to handle saving session state so it is accessible across role instance etc